# Function fires in wrong switch case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement a "lazy state machine" using enums for simple enemy AI but for some reason the logic doesn't work as intended.

I need my enemy to stop from time to time to be in Idle state. But when Idle switch fires, my enemy continues to move despite another state condition for moving script.

What's wrong with my script logic?

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log(state);
    onGround = Physics2D.Raycast(gameObject.transform.position, Vector2.down, groundLength, groundLayer);
    Debug.DrawRay(gameObject.transform.position, Vector2.down * 1f, Color.red);

    isAnythingThere = Physics2D.Raycast(wallDetection.position, Vector2.right * speed, 0.3f, sideInfo);
    RaycastHit2D groundInfo = Physics2D.Raycast(groundDetection.position, Vector2.down, distance);
    RaycastHit2D isPlayerInSight = Physics2D.Raycast(wallDetection.position, Vector2.right * speed, 3f, playerLayer);

    switch (state)
    {
        default:
        case State.patrol:
            if ((groundInfo.collider == false || isAnythingThere) && !isPlayerInSight)
            {
                if (movingRight == true)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Поворот");
                    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
                    movingRight = false;
                    speed = -speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    movingRight = true;
                    speed = -speed;
                }
            }

            if (isPlayerInSight)
            {
                state = State.attack;
            }

            if (enemyIdleCheck == false)
            {
                StartCoroutine("IfEnemyWantsToIdle");
            }

            break;

        case State.attack:
            RaycastHit2D isPlayerThere = Physics2D.Raycast(wallDetection.position, Vector2.right * speed, 3f, playerLayer);
            Debug.DrawRay(wallDetection.transform.position, Vector2.right * speed * 3f, Color.red);

            if (isPlayerThere)
            {
                attackDirection = (playerPosition.position - transform.position).normalized;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!jumpCooldown)
                {
                    state = State.patrol;
                }
            }

            if (jumpCooldown == false)
            {
                jumpTimer = Time.time + jumpCooldownInSeconds;
            }

            break;

        case State.idle:
            if (isPlayerInSight)
            {
                state = State.attack;
            }

            if (!isInIdleState)
            {
                StartCoroutine("IdlingTime");
            }

            break;
    }
}

IEnumerator IfEnemyWantsToIdle()
{
    enemyIdleCheck = true;
    Debug.Log("Checking for idle possibility");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

    if (Random.Range(0, 20) > 10)
    {
        state = State.idle;
    }

    enemyIdleCheck = false;

    if (isPlayerInSight)
    {
        state = State.attack;
        enemyIdleCheck = false;

        yield break;
    }
}

IEnumerator IdlingTime()
{
    isInIdleState = true;

    while (state == State.idle)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2, 4));

        isInIdleState = false;
        state = State.patrol;
    }

    if (isPlayerInSight)
    {
        isInIdleState = false;

        yield break;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (state == State.patrol)
    {
        if (!enemy.isTakingDamage)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movingSpeed * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }

    if (state == State.attack)
    {
        if (!enemy.isTakingDamage)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(attackDirection.x * attackSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }

        if ((Random.Range(0, 100) > 90) && !jumpCooldown && onGround)
        {
            Debug.Log("Прыжок сработал");

            //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * jumpForce);
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpCooldown = true;
            Invoke("JumpCooldownTime", 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are just not adding further force/velocity. The moment you enter the `idle` state you should make sure the `Rigidbody2D` is actually stopped!

```
IEnumerator IdlingTime()
{
    isInIdleState = true;

    // actually stop the movement
    rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
    // you could even do
    rb.isKinematic = true;

    while (state == State.idle)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(2, 4));

        isInIdleState = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        state = State.patrol;
    }

    if (isPlayerInSight)
    {
        isInIdleState = false;
        rb.isKinematic = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

or/and do it in

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    switch(state)
    {
        case State.patrol:
            if (!enemy.isTakingDamage)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(movingSpeed * speed, rb.velocity.y);
            }
            break;
       
        case State.attack:
            if (!enemy.isTakingDamage)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(attackDirection.x * attackSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
            }

            if ((Random.Range(0, 100) > 90) && !jumpCooldown && onGround)
            {
                Debug.Log("Прыжок сработал");

                //rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * jumpForce);
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                jumpCooldown = true;
                Invoke("JumpCooldownTime", 1f);
            }
            break;

        case State.idle
            rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was confused about how this works with player movement, but with enemy movement velocity.x is constant and doesn't requre input. Didn't know that you can use the same switch cases in both Update and FixedUpdate, that's really useful too.